# Error in while-loop

Tags: java, while-loop

So, I have to make a program that generates a random number and then asks the user to input a number. And if the user enters the wrong number, he/she would have to try again. This is my code.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Oblig4 {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Random rg = new Random();
        int randomNumber = rg.nextInt(100);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The program has generated a number,"
                + " You have to guess what number it is.");

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first guess?");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input);

        while (number != randomNumber ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You've guessed wrong");
            String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Try again");
        }

        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations, you guessed right!");

    }
```

My problem is that after the user has guessed wrong, it just loops and says the I've guessed wrong, even though I enter the answer right the second time.

Say that the random number is 4, if I input 3 it says that I am wrong and asks me to try again. If I now enter 4, it still says I am wrong.

EDIT: Found my error. I had to write

```
number = Integer.parseInt(answer)
```

inside the while loop. NOT

```
int number = Integer.parseIng(answer)
```

because that would make a new variable, which I dont want. I just want to change the existing one.

Comment: Without describing your problem, you won't get much help.

Comment: Where did `answer` come from?

Answer (score 3):

You have to put these 2 lines IN your loop:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first guess?");
int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Otherwise you are comparing infinite times the first guess with the random number without asking the user to input a second number.

Comment: I tried this, but then I get the error that "number" isn't defined and I need to create a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the number guessed by the user, just comparing with the same. 
You need to do:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(answer);
```

in the while loop.

Also I think that this code has compilation errors: It lacks of closing } (maybe ommited in the copy/paste) and the variable answer has been not declared.

Edit: Sorry I didn't see the answer before mine (I was trying to reproduce the code on my eclipse), but anyway that code is not wrong but weird since it always ask the user for the first guess :P